# Xamarin.Forms project - ScrollView not working on Windows Phones

Tags: xamarin, scroll, windows-phone

I am developing an universal app with xamarin, and the ScrollView object works just fine on android, iphone, windows 10 pc, but doesent work on windows phones.
How can I fix that?

Comment: To me when I add the ScrollView, the screen goes just black on my Windows phone 8.0, but works on UWP and other platforms... I am using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3